# Add callback function to Java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I want to perform the following operations:

- List the files in a given directory (as a stream)
- Map each file (Path) into a Reader (BufferedReader for example) for a consumer to consume.
- Once a file has been consumed, delete the files

The code would look a bit like this:

```
Stream<Reader> stream = Files.list(Paths.get("myFolder")) // Returns a stream of Path
  .callback(Files::delete)                                // This would have to be called after the reader has been consumed
  .map(Files::newBufferedReader);                         // Maps every path into a Reader
```

If I use `peek()` to delete the files, then the file won't be there when it needs to be mapped into a Reader, so I'd need something that runs after the stream is consumed. 
Any idea?

Comment: You don't have to shoehorn everything into streams you know

Comment: Before you read the file with the associated BufferedReader you could just check if the stream has been deleted with an if-statement.

Comment: You can use stream filters and write your delete logic inside the Predicate and return a boolean value to eliminate/keep those files in the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for a slightly different approach in the end.
I extended the Reader class and created a wrapper, and I simply overrode the `close()` method to perform some additional operations on the file (i.e. rename, delete, move etc) once the reader has been consumed.

```
public class CustomReader extends Reader {
  private Reader reader;
  private File file;

  public CustomReader(File file) {
    this.file = file;
    this.reader = new FileReader(file);
  } 

  [...]
  @Override
  public void close() {
    super.close();
    // Do what you need to do with your file
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [`DELETE_ON_CLOSE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#DELETE_ON_CLOSE) option:

```
Stream<Reader> stream = Files.list(Paths.get("myFolder"))
        // TODO handle IOException
        .map(path -> Files.newInputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE))
        .map(InputStreamReader::new)
        .map(BufferedReader::new);
```